# Where can get user ID and access token?

Tags: php, plaid

I do it first step for authorization? And I don't understand where I can get user ID and access token? I have some errors.

```
<?php

use TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Plaid;


$plaid = new \TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Plaid("........", "....", "sandbox");

$token = $plaid->tokens->create('client_name', 'en', ["US","CA"], 12, ["auth"]);

echo $token ;
?>
```

[2022-07-28T05:57:13.816958+00:00] log.DEBUG: Slim Application Error Type: TypeError Code: 0 Message: TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Resources\Tokens::create(): Argument #4 ($user) must be of type TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Entities\User, int given, called in D:\OpenServer\domains\defi\cp\views\PlaidCreateLinkToken.php on line 20 File: D:\OpenServer\domains\defi\cp\vendor\tomorrow-ideas\plaid-sdk-php\src\Resources\Tokens.php Line: 30 Trace: #0

Comment: I didn't understand anything. You have to clear your question out. Give us more details about what you are doing and what is wrong?

Comment: Yes the question is totally out of focus and is trying to find out how to use the TomorrowIdeas\Plaid SDK with no knowledge of anything. Api doc: https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/ Plaid SDK: https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php